# Bundle Products and tax

Tags: product, price, tax, bundled-product

I have a problem on Magento where if I sell a bundle product, despite setting the price to dynamic and overriding the default tax setting from 'None' to 'Taxable Goods' I find that every order and invoice with a sale of a bundle product shows 0 tax...

Any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 1):

The tax is calculated per item, so you have to set "Taxable Goods" for each simple product not for the bundle itself.

Comment: That's what's already been set, if the simple product is purchased, tax is shown correctly. If the bundle is bought through Amazon via M2E pro, it works, but if it's bought via eBay or other channels it seems to not bother calculating.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a problem itself with M2E pro and will be fixed in a future release. I can confirm that grouped products pose no such difficulty and will be making more use of grouped products in future to bypass this problem until it's fixed